# Install Firefox extension using windows registry

Tags: windows, firefox-addon, registry, installation

I have followed the instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry) [MDC - Adding Extensions using the Windows Registry], 
but haven't been able to get Firefox to automatically install my extension when I restart it.

I have written an application that is half windows service and half FF extension. I have built an installer and want it to be able to install the Firefox extension along with the service.

So far I have tried the following things:

- Removing my dev version of the
  extension from FF first
- Removing the
  pointer file to my dev version of the
  extension from my profile dir
- Removing my "dev" profile completelly
  so that FF only has a "default"
  profile
- Running FF without the
  -no-remote and -P switches I setup for the dev environment
- Trying the
  key in both HKEY_CURRENT_USER and
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
- Carefully checking
  the ID and Paths I have used
- Trying
  Paths that don't include spaces
- Trying the Paths in Quotes
- Trying a
  trailing \ at the end of the path
- Trying the .xpi filename at the end of the path instead of just the dir name
- Building the XPI using the Extension
  Builder plugin instead of manually
  (although my manual build would
  install just fine if I dragged it to
  FF)

I'm using FF3.5.2 on Windows 2003 Server
(could it be a W2K3 install security issue?)

UPDATE: Now tested also on WinXP FF3.0.11. Same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I figured it out myself! I miss-read one line of the instructions!!!

> "the location of the unpacked XPI"

I must be losing my mind. For some reason I reread this as the "packed XPI" over and over!!!
(I feel very silly now)

The answer was to use the unpacked files in the install dir not the .xpi file.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that it's really important to have back-slash in the file path, ex: [TARGETDIR]Extension\Firefox\